# Padarn OpenNetCF System.Argument.Exception when starting the server

Tags: c#, server, opennetcf, padarn

I'm getting a "OpenNetCf - Argument Exception" when I try to start the server on the desktop (windows 8.1)

```
Srvr = new OpenNETCF.Web.Server.WebServer();
   Srvr.Start();
```

However, I can't see a problem with the config file. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="WebServer" type="OpenNETCF.Web.Configuration.ServerConfigurationHandler, opennetcf.web"/>
        <section name ="httpRuntime" type="OpenNETCF.Web.Configuration.HttpRuntimeConfigurationHandler, opennetcf.web"/>
    </configSections>
    <WebServer
        UseSsl="false" 
        LocalIP="0.0.0.0"
        DefaultPort="80"
        MaxConnections="20"
        DocumentRoot=".\Inetpub\"
        Logging="false">
        <DefaultDocuments>
            <Document>Login.aspx</Document>
        </DefaultDocuments>
        <VirtualDirectories />
        <Cookies />
        <Caching />
    </WebServer>
    <httpRuntime
        maxRequestLength="4096"
        requestLengthDiskThreshold="256" />
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely attempting to use the Compact Framework version of the binaries.  While the Padarn code base work for Compact Framework, Full Framework and Mono, the compiled assemblies are different and you must use the appropriate one based on your runtime environment.